# How can I select DISTINCT records including DATETIME when DATETIME is different?

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I need to pull data for a report from a SQL Server 2008 R2 database that lists all products built for a given day.  The records can have multiple entries in the same day, but I only want to count the items one time.

Example record:

```
SerialNumber VARCHAR(20)
OrderNumber VARCHAR(50)
Price DECIMAL(7,2)
TestDateTime DATETIME
```

My view query might look something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT OrderNumber, SerialNumber, Price, TestDateTime 
FROM TestTable
ORDER BY OrderNumber, SerialNumber
```

...and then the report query would look something like this:

```
SELECT OrderNumber, SerialNumber, Price
FROM TestView
WHERE CONVERT(date, getdate()) = CONVERT(date, TestDateTime)
```

...except then I get a separate (duplicate) record for each datetime.  I need the datetime field as I will be selecting records from the view based on date, but I also want an accurate total of the price fields for a given OrderNumber so I only want to see each SerialNumber once.

Any ideas?

Next question - how do I get the total price for all rows with the same OrderNumber?  Maybe that should be a separate question...

Comment: You need the date -- which date? Oldest, newest?

Comment: It looks like you may have a `JOIN` where you have `TestTable`. You're oversimplifying your query to help us understand it. If that is the case, please post the full query.

Comment: Not a very complete question.  You say built for a given day but there is now where date = in your query.  Do you mean multiple entries per day and you want want row for each product per day?  Even then what if the price changes.   Come on if you want help but some effort in the question.

Comment: I simplified the question to avoid contextual overload, or whatever you want to call it. However, adding a sample report query as well as the view query really makes it a lot clearer, almost a trivial problem. Still, a couple people understood what I was asking without it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you considered just casting it to a date

```
SELECT DISTINCT OrderNumber, SerialNumber, Price, cast(TestDateTime  as date) testDate
FROM TestTable
ORDER BY OrderNumber, SerialNumber
```

Comment: That does it!  By not including the time portion of the datetime, the DISTINCT clause now works as it should...  thanks!